# Difference between every 6th row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I can calculate difference between every 6th row in SQL Server 2016? For example:

```
Col1     Col2   Diff
-----    ----   ----
1       2      NULL
2       4      NULL
3       6      NULL 
4       10     NULL
5       14     NULL 
6       18     NULL 
7       20     18
8       22     18
9       30     24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*, col2 - lag(col2, 6) over (order by col1) as diff6
from t;
```

The second (and not frequently used) argument to `lag()` and `lead()` is offset.  It returns `NULL` if the value is not there, which seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Lag() is the straight option. Below is an another way using JOIN.

```
WITH STable
AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rownum FROM table
)

Select x.col1, x.col2, x.col2 - y.col2 AS diff
from STable x
Left Join STable y
ON x.rownum = y.rownum + 6
```